# Setting delegate results in crash, leaving it null doesn't

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode6

I'm trying to do something unusual out of sheer curiosity/masochism.

There's a tutorial called [Swiftris](https://www.bloc.io/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift). It's based on Swift 2, but I'm stuck with Swift 1 using Xcode 6. I can't use the debugger because it requires administrator privilege on the one machine I have access to. So I've put a text label on in my view controller for showing debug information.

So yeah, already this is a weird thing I'm trying to do. But I really want to learn this stuff.

So here's my code. There are two relevant files, GameController.swift and Swiftris.swift.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, SwiftrisDelegate {

    var scene: GameScene!
    var swiftris: Swiftris!

    var panPointReference:CGPoint?

    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        //swiftris.delegate = self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        swiftris.delegate? = self
    }

    // Leaving out the delegate functions here. I do implement them,
    // I'm just not showing them, and they don't seem to affect the
    // error. I've checked.

    func updateErrorLabel(s: String) {
        errorLabel.text = s
    }
}
```

and

```
protocol SwiftrisDelegate {
    func gameDidEnd(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func gameDidBegin(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func gameShapeDidLand(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func gameShapeDidMove(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func gameShapeDidDrop(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func gameDidLevelUp(swiftris: Swiftris)
    func updateErrorLabel(s: String)
}

class Swiftris {
    var blockArray:Array2D<Block>
    var nextShape:Shape?
    var fallingShape:Shape?
    var delegate:SwiftrisDelegate?

    var score = 0;
    var level = 1;

    init() {
        fallingShape = nil
        nextShape = nil
        blockArray = Array2D<Block>(columns: NumColumns, rows: NumRows)
        delegate?.updateErrorLabel("init")
    }

    func beginGame() {
        delegate?.updateErrorLabel("game beginning")
        if (nextShape == nil) {
            nextShape = Shape.random(PreviewColumn, startingRow: PreviewRow)
        }
        delegate?.gameDidBegin(self)
    }

    // Bunch of stuff excluded here that doesn't seem to matter
}
```

As you can see, in Swiftris I have a delegate that is for sending debug strings, and in GameViewController I set Swiftris's delegate to be myself so Swiftris can talk indirectly to my error label.

If I **don't** set it, there is no update to the error label, but there is also no crash, probably because that type is optional. If I **do** set, it crashes, complaining, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". How can this thing be nil?

Comment: Init swiftris ->  var swiftris: Swiftris! = Swiftris()  and delegate it in -> override init()

Comment: Turns out I had trimmed out some important code. I do instantiate Swiftris in  viewDidLoad. So I guess the problem was trying to set swiftris.delegate in the init function because that happens before viewDidLoad. (I'm aware of these concerns from my experience with other languages and platforms, but somehow the different environment has me unsure of where to look, probably because I know I don't know what I don't know, and that leaves open a daunting amount of possibilities to check.)

Comment: Init it when you declare the var, after set delegate in viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize swiftris before setting the delegate:

```
override init() {
        super.init()
        swiftris = Swiftris()
        swiftris.delegate = self
    }
```